# Use overridePendingTransition in conjuction with recreate(). Can it be done?

Tags: android, animation, recreate, overridependingtransition

I've been using Android's overridePendingTransition method to animate my activity page transitions with great success.  Example shown

```
startActivity(new Intent(GetTagActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

I have a situation that I need to "refresh" a page and desire a fade transition.  Without going into the details, I can't use the `StartActivity(...)`method to call the refresh (which would allow for the animation call).

Using `recreate()`works perfect to "refresh" the page, however I haven't been able to add the transition animation.  This hasn't worked.

```
recreate();
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

nor this

```
recreate().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

Can fade animation (or any activity transition) be used with recreate()?

Comment: What about `finish()` followed by `startActivity()`?

Comment: Any updates on this? I stumbled across same requirement.

Comment: No update specifically to the question, however since this post, I have learned how to use activity flags in conjunction with onNewIntent that has allowed me to  mimic recreate() with a startActivity() call and use animation. Doesn't work for every situation but is something to look into.

Answer (score -3):

you can user this (Kotlin code)

```
  override fun recreate() {
    finish()
    startActivity(Intent(this,this.javaClass))
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);


}
```

Comment: my question specifically stated not to use the startActivity() method.